# Need help to add page for a company in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

This theme has a page like this   :

for category :
: http://www.aankha.com/cc/category/business-finances/

for Author/User  :

http://www.aankha.com/cc/author/admin/

I want to create a similar page

for company: 
something like this  :
/cc/company/abc_company/

Can somebody please suggest me any plugin that can do it or if I can do it manually how can I do that?

Answer (score -1):

The link shared by you i.e. "http://www.aankha.com/cc/category/business-finances/" is for category but if you want to create a page with such type URL then first you have to create a new page with name or title "company" and then create another page with name or title "abc_company" and assign page "company" as parent page of "abc_company" from the select box and save your page.Now view your page in browser you will see the desired URL you wished for.

Comment: Thank you for the manual solution but the pages I mentioned are created automatically but not manually. Each author pages are automatically created as soon as they register and category page when category is created. how can I do that?

Answer (score -1):

- You can create a parent page called as company
- And the child pages such abc_company , etc.
- when you publish the child page select the parent as company

  URL will look like -  /company/abc_company/

or

create a category called as company and add subcategories(abc_company) under category

Comment: Thank you for your solutions but the pages I mentioned are created automatically but not manually. Each author pages are automatically created as soon as they register and category page when category is created. how can I do that?